# FATAL: Error, Visual Studio required for using ClangCL on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-c++, nuitka

while trying to use Nuitka on anaconda prompt to obfuscate python script pass.py 
(would like to use clang compiler not gcc)
after typing below cmd:

```
python -m nuitka --clang --follow-imports pass.py
```

it shows this error message:

```
FATAL: Error, Visual Studio required for using ClangCL on Windows.
```

However I've installed Microsoft visual studio community 2022 edition with C++ and python packages
where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved by below steps:
1)installed individual components from visual studio installer:

[image]

2)added to path system variable: clang.exe, clang++.exe and clang-cl.exe paths, in my system they are in:

```
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin
  C:\Users\Dalia\anaconda3\pkgs\clang-14.0.6-h44fa016_0\Library\bin\
```